# How to access a variable passed from AngularJS via http in PHP?

Tags: php, angularjs

I am passing an object into a PHP script like this:

```
$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'updateCoins.php',
    data: {flips: $scope.data.flips, error: $scope.data.pe},
})
```

In my PHP script I tried:

```
$data = file_get_contents("php://input");
```

and

```
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents("php://input"));
```

I then tried echoing back the received value like this:

```
echo $data.flips
```

or

```
echo $data[flips]
```

or

```
echo $data->flips
```

I keep on getting either a blank result or the word "flips" back. How do I access those variables?

Comment: its in the post suerperglobal `echo $_POST['flips'];`

Comment: There's no reason to use `$_POST` over `php://input`, especially if you're sending JSON -- you're fine with what you're doing there already. Try dumping `$data` to see what's actually in it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the data was sent JSON-encoded, then it would make sense to `json_decode()`.  I suspect that your data is `x-www-form-urlencoded` (eg: *name=john&age=7*).  In this case, PHP parses it into the `$_POST` array for you.  If you wish to do it on your own, and handle either case, you could do something like:

```
// Read content-type to determine whether it's JSON data
$type = $_SERVER["CONTENT_TYPE"];
$content = file_get_contents('php://input');

if(strpos($type,'json') > -1):
    $data = json_decode($content, true);
else:
    parse_str($content, $data);
endif;

print_r($data);
```

You can always visually inspect the data with `echo file_get_contents('php://input');`

Comment: When I try to echo 'file_get_contents', I get this error in the console: POST http://msolonko.net/updateCoins.php 500 (Internal Server Error)  AND Possibly unhandled rejection: {"data":"","status":500,"config":{"method":"POST","transformRequest":[null],"transformResponse":[null],"jsonpCallbackParam":"callback","url":"updateCoins.php","data":{"flips":10,"error":20},"headers":{"Accept":"application/json, text/plain, */*","Content-Type":"application/json;charset=utf-8"}},"statusText":"Internal Server Error"}

Comment: My data is in JSON - your code helped me realize that and then I used print_r to see the array structure.

Answer (score 1):

Php won't grab the posted data from $_POST if the post is formatted in json. You can serialize the post data and submit it thusly

```
var data = 'flips='+$scope.data.flips+'&error='+$scope.data.pe;

$http({
    method: 'POST',
    url: 'updateCoins.php',
    headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'},
    data: data
});
```

OR you can do like BeetleJuice recommended. In my application I just do the following so that the rest of the code is uninterrupted.

```
if (empty($_POST) && file_get_contents('php://input')!==""){
    $_POST = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'), true);
}
```

at which point you can access it with `$_POST['flips']` and `$_POST['error']`